# Why do I get this error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'index')"?

Tags: angular

I'm using this code in my template:

```
<mat-tab-group   mat-align-tabs="start"  (selectedTabChange)="ngOnInit($event)">
```

ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit(evt: any) {
  this.api.getApi().subscribe( ({tool, beuty}) => {
    this.beu = beuty.slice(0,this.i+=18);
    this.tools = tool.slice(0,this.i+=18);
    if (evt.index === 0) { 
      console.log('ddd');
    }
  })
}
```

When I load the website I see this error in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'index')
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

> @Output()
> selectedTabChange: EventEmitter. Event emitted when the tab selection has changed.

Do not run method `ngOnInit()` with `selectedTabChange` listener  - thats a lifecycle hook automatically run on component build https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit#ngoninit and it wouldn't be considered good practice to do so. Make a new method for tab change `onTabChange()` and name it accordingly.

When component is being created `ngOnInit()` runs in TS file, where is the `evt`? It can't be found, so its `undefined`. `evt` is not declared anywhere in TS file thus it errors - the Event is only sent from template. `ngOnInit()` is run before template is rendered and though it is possible to give params to the method it's not needed in your case.

```js
 onTabChange(event: any) {
    console.log(event)
  }
```

```html
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwakqv?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html

Answer (score 0):

As Joosep Part says rearrange your code

```
ngOnInit(evt: any) {
  //in ngOnInit call to the function with and argument create "on fly"
  this.getData({evt:0})
}

getData(evt: any)
{
  this.api.getApi().subscribe( ({tool, beuty}) => {
    this.beu = beuty.slice(0,this.i+=18);
    this.tools = tool.slice(0,this.i+=18);
    if (evt.index === 0) { 
      console.log('ddd');
    }
}

<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start (selectedTabChange)="getData($event)">
```

NOTE: In general try to avoid call to ngOnInit from .html, ngOnInit should be called only in the lifecycle hook of our component